# how to make box plot with R with interrupted Y axis

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

This is a sample of my data. It's a tab delimited file with a header.

```
X1      X2      X3      X4
1.3     0.5     0.1     1
NA      0.3     0.4     3
NA      0.2     0.3     0.3
NA      0.1     3       0.2
NA      27      5       56
NA      NA      10      0.01
```

I would like to get a `boxplot` from this data. The problem is that I want to *interrupt* the plot at `10` and `50` on `Y-axis`. I want a *bigger plot size before 10* and a *smaller plot size after* that. I don't know how to plot with 2 gaps in `Y-axis`. I tried with `axis.break` and `gap.boxplot` but as my programming skills with R are very limited so I am unable to use both of these methods properly. I'd be grateful for any hints to accomplish this?

Comment: X1      X2      X3      X4<br />
1.344827586     0.5     0.1     1<br />
NA      0.3     0.4     3<br />
NA      0.2     0.3     0.3<br />
NA      0.1     3       0.2<br />
NA      27      5       56<br />
NA      NA      10      0.01<br />

Comment: I don't know why my file is shown as one line. It has 7 rows and 4 columns.

Comment: Hi welcome to stack overflow.  The comments box offers less formatting options. Please use the proper body of the question. (You should see an option to edit your question)

Comment: @vaqaardar, I've edited the post. What do you mean "interrupt the plot".. Is there an image you can link us to as to how you'd like the plot to look like?

Comment: http://rgm3.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM/r_function?p=plotrix&f=gap.boxplot

Comment: http://rgm3.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM/r_function?p=plotrix&f=gap.boxplot

Comment: the 2 links posted above have gapped box plots but on the upper and lower blocks there is no Y-axis labelling shown.

Comment: this example has Y-axis labelled after the gap as well but this is not a box plot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427376/rescale-axis-in-grouped-scatter-plots-with-use-of-axes-breaks

Comment: Please let me know if I need to explain my question with more examples?

Comment: What happened when you tried to use `gap.boxplot`?

Comment: I get a warning message that some data points are in the gap. Also, I cannot label the Y-axis after the break. I tried using axis.break but the Y-axis labelling gets reversed after the break.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really clear on what you want, and what you mean by "bigger plot size before 10 and a smaller plot size after that". Do you mean different scales? That is a bad idea,  I think, and I don't believe it would be straightforward.

Here's how to break the axis twice (I'm guessing on the regions to exclude):

```
library(plotrix)
library(reshape2)
a <- read.table(textConnection("X1 X2 X3 X4
        1.3 0.5 0.1 1
        NA 0.3 0.4 3
        NA 0.2 0.3 0.3
        NA 0.1 3 0.2
        NA 27 5 56
        NA NA 10 0.01"),sep=" ",header=T)
am <-melt(a) #from reshape2 - allows categorical variables to be in one column
gap.boxplot(am$value ~ am$variable, #means the values are plotted againsy variable
gap=list(top=c(30,50),bottom=c(10,24)), #specifies regions of Y axis to exclude
axis.labels=T) #should label all the Y axis, doesn't seem to work well
```

[image]

Comment: Can anyone please fix it? Thank you!